# How do I train gpt 2 from scratch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nlg

I want to train gpt 2 from scratch but there is only fine-tuning approach based on pretrained models in articles I found.
I've used this https://github.com/nshepperd/gpt-2 for train with existing model. Should I edit these Python scripts to train from scratch?

Comment: Tell more info using tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in 'issues' of this repo https://github.com/nshepperd/gpt-2

> If you want to not use the released model at all, for instance because
>   you want to train a model with incompatible hyperparameters, it should
>   be sufficient to just skip the restore from the released model
>   checkpoint (around train.py:164-177) on your first run so the
>   parameters will all be randomly initialized.